# How do I create the text like this website? (css/javascript)

Tags: javascript, css, templates, effects

http://posterous.com/
If you look on the very bottom/right there is "API, Privacy, Terms"

They are "shadowed" text. And they have this indentation in them.
Is there an easy open-source way to do this?

Comment: I recommend firebug. Go google it, download it, install it and use it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's CSS3:

```
text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

They are using the CSS-Property [text-shadow](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/text-shadow).

Answer (score 1):

If you use a modern browser( Firefox + firebug, Safari on Mac, Chrome, Opera, IE8) you can right click on an element in a page and use the command called Inspect(vary from browser to browser).

You will see a table with all the CSS properties, the "text-shadow" in this case.